# Can I use Bluetooth 4.1 headphones with Bluetooth 3.0 Smartwatch?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am going to buy a smartwatch which runs Bluetooth 3.0. Will I be able to use it with my headphone which is a Blutooth 4.1 device?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Headphones generally includes A2DP, HFP, AVRCP and HSP profiles. These profiles are present with BT version 4.1 as well. You can definitely go and buy Version 4.1 headphones for your Bluetooth 3.0 device.

One such Bluetooth 4.1 headphone example is: [JBL 4.1 Headphone](https://www.jbl.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Harman/default/dw7f9af328/pdfs/Specification%20sheet%20-%20JBL%20Everest%20300%20(English)%20%20New.pdf)